# Finding a rational non-zero of a multivariate polynomial in polynomial time

Tags: complexity-theory

Suppose we have a degree $m$ multivariate polynomial $p(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m)$ in $n$ variables (by degree I mean the highest sum of powers of factors in any monomial term). Such a polynomial can have infinitely many rational zeros. Suppose we have landed at one of them, then what is an efficient way to escape from the zeros? Schwartz's theorem gives us 
that $p$ can be zero on an at most half of the integer points in any 2m x 2m x 2m x ... n-cube set of points such as the points with x,y,z,... in {0, 1, ..., d}, but this is computationally inefficient. Is there a better way to find a non-zero?

In the actual problem I'm trying to solve, there are restrictions on the $x_i$'s. I'm hoping to find a criterion that I can satisfy within these restrictions, so the more, the merrier!

Comment: Why is choosing a random point inefficient? On average you only need to test two random points. That's faster than any sophisticated method you can think of.

Comment: Hi Yuval. Yes, this follows from Schwartz-Zippel lemma, right? But we really need to be certain that after polynomially many steps we will have at least one non-zero. This problem is arose in the context of an attempt to prove some quantity is #P-hard. So we are trying to get a contradiction here and I'm not aware of a result that says that if as in our case, we get the answer with probability 0.5, then the problem is polynomially computable. Don't see how to link the two...

Comment: So you're interested only in deterministic algorithms. In that case, your problem is some variant of polynomial identity testing (PID), which is suspected to be in P but not known to be so. Perhaps you should explain better what you're after.

Comment: So you're saying that asking for a deterministic polynomial time algorithm for finding a non-zero of a multivariate polynomial is equivalent to the PID problem? But suppose we know our polynomial not to be zero, is it solvable then?

Comment: I wasn't saying that. It's a *variant* of PID, something very similar to PID, which probably requires the same techniques as PID, and perhaps even provably equivalent to PID. For example, an algorithm that finds a non-zero of a non-zero polynomial can be used to decide whether a given polynomial is non-zero: just run it and test that the result is indeed non-zero.

Comment: Thank you, Yuval, I will look into the PID problem. For more context, our polynomial is actually the numerator of a determinant which we are trying to make non-zero, so it is of a very specific form.